# Quartz cron expression for cron triggers executed every Nth Hour/Day/Week/Month

Tags: quartz-scheduler, scheduler, crontrigger

I am developing an application that gives the user the ability to schedule some activity.
Inputs that are provided by user are

1. Value of N
2. Option amongst Hour/Day/Week/Month
3. Start Date
4. Start Time

I am unable to get the cron expressions right for each of the repeat interval type i.e. Hour/Day/Week/Month so that the trigger time is calculated from the start date.

Answer (score 2):

Quartz documentation suggests using a SimpleTrigger http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/cookbook/BiDailyTrigger.html, an example for every other day:

```
Trigger trigger = new SimpleTrigger("trigger1", "group1");
trigger.setRepeatCount(SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY);
// 24 hours * 60(minutes per hour) * 60(seconds per minute) * 1000(milliseconds per second)
trigger.setRepeatInterval(2L * 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L);
```

Note that you will need to set the trigger start time and the misfire rule.

Answer (score 0):

I think is a good start of how to configure triggers:

http://www.opensymphony.com/quartz/wikidocs/CronTriggers%20Tutorial.html

Comment: I have already looked into this in detail. But i have this unique req.
Let me try drafting a use case that would explain what i am trying to do.

User story => I want to perform some abc every 3 hours starting from 1755 hours on 30/10/2009

so, the 1st activity on 30/10/2009 1755
2nd on 30/10/2009 2055
3rd on 30/10/2009 2355
4th on 31/10/2009 0255
and so on....

Expression:
1. 0 55 */3 * * ? * => for this trigger time is calculated from 00 hours and s0 it 1st fires at 1855 and not 1755
2. 0 55 17/3 * * ? * => for this trigger first fires on 1755, 2055 & 2355 thats it now it will fire next day.

Comment: U see none of the possible expression solves my issue.
I am out of ideas now. Please provide me with some pointers on this.